# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

Tags: python, nlp, part-of-speech

I tried to load embedding file for Parts-of-speech analysis with NLP . But It shows

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-94170a7f0621> in <module>()
      2 
      3 def get_coefs(word,*arr): return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32')
----> 4 embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.split(" ")) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE))

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

What's should I do?

```py
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
    
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
    
EMBEDDING_FILE = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/ML/paragram_300_sl999-2.txt', encoding= 'unicode_escape', sep=" ", header=None)
    
def get_coefs(word,*arr): 
    return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32')

embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.split(" ")) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE))
```

Comment: can you add a sample of text file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by converting `txt` file to `pandas.DataFrame`. You can simply use the text file like this:

```
import numpy as np 
EMBEDDING_FILE = '../input/paragram-300-sl999/paragram_300_sl999.txt'
def get_coefs(word,*arr): return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32')
embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.split(" ")) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') if len(o)>100)
print(type(embeddings_index), type(embeddings_index['the']), embeddings_index['the'].shape, len(list(embeddings_index.keys())))
```

output:

```
<class 'dict'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (300,) 66199
```

Comment: @lui carmen could the answer help?